# Super simple inexact differential ydx.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential

Really quick, why the integral of ydx from (0,0) to (1,1) is 1/2 and from (0,0) to (1,0) and from (1,0) to (1,1) is 0, I can kind of understand the answer by looking at drawn graphs, but I never actually solved integrals as points, and this looks like a multivariable calculus integral, but there is no double integral so I'm just really confused.
$\int_{(0,0)}^{(1,1)}ydx=\int_0^1xdx=1/2$ vs $\int_{(0,0)}^{(1,0)}ydx + \int_{(1,0)}^{(1,1)}ydx = 0$ [image: Real quick drawing of different paths]
How do I "write" the graphs as integrals? And where can I learn more about these "points" integrals? (I saw this one in a thermodynamics book)

Comment: These are just line integrals. You need to parameterise the curve first before integrating. Going directly from $(0,0)$ to $(1,1)$ in a straight line is parameterised by $$\boldsymbol{r}(t) = (x(t),y(t)) = (0,0) + t(1-0,1-0) = (t, t)$$ from $t: 0 \to 1$. Hence the line integral is equal to $$\int_{C} y dx = \int_{0}^{1} t dt = 1/2$$ If you go along the x axis, you should get $\boldsymbol{r}(t) = (0,0) + t(1-0,0-0) = (t, 0), t:0 \to 1$ so that $$\int_{C} y dx = \int_{0}^{1} 0 \ dt = 0$$ I'll leave you to do the line integral from $(1,0)$ to $(1,1)$.

Comment: What is a book you recommend to learn this topic with many exercise/examples?